# Mac alternative to SQL server management studio?

Tags: sql-server, windows, macos, sql-server-2008, ssms

I am on Windows so SQL server management studio works fine for me. However, my application is hosted and my client needs to make some entries in DB and he has Mac. How can we get over this issue? Is there any MAC option for SSMS?

Thanks!

Comment: So, you don't really need OS independent (e.g. Java) do you, you *need* a Mac OSX solution.

Comment: @Damien: Yeah, for now Mac would do.

Comment: Are you not worried about giving your client access not to just tables and databases but the entire server by providing them access to the SSMS console? You could create a SSIS package that reads a file and inserts data. CLient can just drop the file somewhere? I dont know of a SSMS alternative for Mac.

Comment: *However, my application is hosted and my client needs to make some entries in DB and he has Mac* That sounds like something that should be in the application...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: AquaDataStudio too. [Blog post here that might be useful](http://madelinebertrand.com/2012/04/20/re-blog-using-a-mac-in-a-windows-world/). Seriously, though, just use a virtual machine, or remote desktop.

Comment: Hey Jack. You could try my app SQLPro for MSSQL (http://www.macsqlclient.com/). Its a lightweight SQL Server database client which has been getting great reviews. It is also available via the mac app store.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

DbVisualizer is OS independent using java.

http://www.dbvis.com/download/

This was answered years ago. Another option is Azure Data Studio

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/download-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

I use RazorSQL.  It works on OS X, Windows and Linux so you can use one tool across all platforms, if you like.

http://www.razorsql.com/

Comment: RazorSQL isn't free. 30 day free trial (for people who are looking for free)

Comment: as mentioned RazorSQL is not free, Try Azure data studio, or may be check list here: https://qawithexperts.com/article/sql/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-alternatives-mac-windows-l/445