# How to work on OSX using dotnetcore, but production will have sql-server

Tags: sql-server, .net-core

Do you think it would be a good idea to develop a dotnetcore application on OSX using mysql/postgresql as the database.  But in production the database will be sql server.

I really enjoy working on my OSX laptop over windows, but the project requires sql-server when I push to PROD.

Comment: But Entity framework should make it smooth no?

Comment: You can always connect to a sql server using the network. While EF Core does abstract over DB providers, managing migrations for multiple ones is a bit hard - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers

Comment: You could use [mssql-server-linux](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-linux/) which is a SQL Server 2017 Docker image.

Comment: @Boggin  how do I connect to it as I can't run management studio on osx...

Comment: [Mac alternative to SQL server management studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14434220/mac-alternative-to-sql-server-management-studio#14609280) gives some solutions. If your macos machine has enough RAM there's also the option of running Windows under Parallels. With 8GB this is slow but with 16GB it's seamless.

Comment: Don't forget to post an answer showing how you manage this in the end.